# Express $y$ through $R$ and $x$.

Tags: trigonometry

How can I express $y$ through $R$ and $x$?
$$y=R \pm \sqrt{R^2-\bigg(R\arccos \left(\mp1 \pm \frac{y}{R} \right) -x \bigg)^2}$$

It can be transformed into this :
$$y=\pm R \cos\left( \frac{\sqrt{2yR-y^2}+x}{R}\right)-R$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because $R$ and $x$ don't determine $y$. For example, consider $R=1, x=0$, and if you [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%20(sqrt(2y-y%5E2))%20-1%20-y%20from%20-1%20to%204) the function $\cos(\sqrt{2y-y^2})-1-y$ you can see it has two solutions.

---

Edit: the second equation doesn't follow from the first. The plot of the first is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bsqrt(1-(arccos(-1%2By))%5E2)-y) and it has two real solutions: maybe adding some conditions can help finding a closed formula for $y$. The correct second equation is $y = R \pm R \cos(\frac{x \pm \sqrt{-y^2+2Ry}}{R})$, with the two $\pm$ independent from each other, the internal one coming from resolving a second degree equation.

Comment: So that is strange, because this equation must describe movement of a point on a circle, that is rolling on the X axis.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Are you sure you derived the second equation correctly? Because I only used that... also, maybe if you add some condition...

Comment: The second equation is not a derivative.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия "how you derived..?" as "are you correct the steps you did are right..?"

Comment: Yes, but at first step I squared the root, and after this lost +- before root, but I think, it is ok.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия I believe you made a mistake ;) $y = R \pm R \cos(\frac{x \pm \sqrt{y^2-2yR}}{R})$ with the two $\pm$ independent from each other

Comment: There is 2yR-y^2, not y^2-2yR. And the equation $y = R \pm R \cos(\frac{x \pm \sqrt{2yR-y^2}}{R})$ has only one real solution, when first equation has two.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия two solutions: one for the $+$, one for the $-$

Comment: And the first equation has [two](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+sqrt(1-(arccos(-1+y))%5E2)-y) for + and [two](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-sqrt(1-(arccos(1-y))%5E2)-y) for -.